# In JMeter, Getting "Object moved here" response for login post request while performing Load test in Asp.net Web app

Tags: asp.net, performance, jmeter, http-headers, load-testing

I have performed Load testing in Asp.net application using JMeter. While login, am getting "Object Moved Here" message as response.

In View result tree, I found Login main sampler displaying with two sub samplers.
In that one sub sampler is with the "Object Moved Here" message.

In my test plan, I have handled
- CSS/JQUERY Extractor to extract dynamic values "Event validation" & "View State"
- HTTP Cookie manager(Checked "Clear cookies each iteration" & Cookie policy: Compatibility)

Note: Except the Login functionality request & response, all the other HTTP samplers in my test plan are worked as expected.

Anybody have any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

[Well-behaved JMeter test should do exactly what real browser is doing](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser), to wit:

- send the same HTTP requests as real browser does
- handle "embedded resources" (images, scripts, styles, fonts) like real browser does
- properly mimic [AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) requests
- simulate browser [headers](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager), [cache](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cache_Manager) and [cookies](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager)

In particular your case `Object moved here` request stands for a [HTTP Redirect](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_redirect_webpage.asp), to wit first request gets [3xx status code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status#Redirection_messages) and being pointed to another location.

You should verify what real browser is doing using Network tab of its [developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools) and ensure that JMeter is doing the same. If the browser is not doing the redirect you can explicitly tell JMeter not to follow the redirects by unticking `Redirect Automatically` and/or `Follow Redirects` boxes in the HTTP Request sampler

[image: JMeter Follow Redirects]

Comment: As you stated, i got the "302 status code" in the first request and it pointed towards another location. I have verified the real browsers responses and I unchecked "Follow redirects" & "Redirect automatically" check boxes. But still i am facing the same issue. Do you have any other idea on this.   Note:I have found "Character length" of the extracted view state & event validation variable is differ from the value in the browsers response.